# How to align Hint Text into centre in Text Field?

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to add alignment to the hint-text inside Text-field.but it is not working. How to bring it to centre??
How to write text in curved shape???

```
 Container(
           child: new TextFormField(
                       controller: _pass,
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
                       decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                             hintText: " PASSWORD", ), )),
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: Please edit your question to add code, and remove the comment.

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9149

Comment: @PhilippReichart i have edited code.. any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: @ShyjuM i have tried it already

Answer (score 54):

use `textAlign: TextAlign.center,` inside TextFormField or textfield

here is the code

[image]

The Output Like This

[image]

Answer (score 32):

My problem was the auto content padding:

```
TextField(
     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
     hintText: "hola mundo",
   ),
),
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Or we can use `EdgeInsets.zero`

Answer (score 14):

The **textHint** will have the same Alignment as the input text. So you can try the code below to achieve what you're looking for:

```
TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 5,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      autofocus: true,
      initialValue: '',
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'some hint',
        counterText: "",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: but if the font size of the hint text is not the same size of the field text, hint text will not be aligned vertically in the center, it will be below the center line.

Answer (score 11):

***Note:*** specific case, but might help others who tried everything else from this thread.

I had a design from which I copied all the paddings and alignments, but I somehow couldn't center the hint text, it was always a few pixels closer to the top edge.

The only thing that worked was finding out that there was a specific **text height** set in the design. After I applied that, everything aligned perfectly.

```
InputDecoration(
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: _smallFontSize, // or whatever
    height: 1.4, //                                <----- this was the key
  ),
  // other properties...
);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can add  textAlign: TextAlign.center to your code 
here is my code and its works:

```
new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),

                child:
                new TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                    hintText: 'REF: 2',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 3):

all of the answers work for the fixed-sized text fields but in my case, I m using a dynamically sized container that parents my text field

```
AnimatedContainer(
      width: (!widget.scrollController.hasClients ||
              widget.scrollController.positions.length > 1)
          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toDouble()
          : max(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                  widget.scrollController.offset.roundToDouble(),
              (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80.w).toDouble()),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 40.h),
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        expands: true,
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: null,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: MyAppColors.primaryColor1,
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: 
            BorderRadius.circular(15.w)),
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              size: 20.w,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            hintText: 'Songs, albums or artists',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,

            hintStyle: 
      
      
     Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2!.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                fontSize: 18.sp,
            )),
     
      ),
    );
```

the solution that worked for me is that I set expand parameter to true and set these parameters:

```
  minLines: null,
  maxLines: null,
  expands: true,
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center
```

the min and max line must be set to null in order to expand.
that is the only solution I found cuz in another way my hint text gain extra padding even I set the content padding to zero my hint text is not centered in other screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following attribute of TextFormField:

```
        textAlign: TextAlign.center
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the textAlign property to center as well as the content padding to EdgeInsets.all(0)

```
_inputValue({final height, final width}) {
    return Container(
      height: height / 18,
      width: width / 2.5,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: TextFormField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          hintText: 'Enter',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.mainBlue),
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.mainBlue),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This used to work earlier but now it doesn't. There's a [recently opened issue in flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15079) which you can follow

**Edit**
Now works as expected.