# Flutter TextField Hint or Text Not Align CenterLeft while set the Container height 40

Tags: flutter, mobile, alignment

I have used `TextField` inside `Container` with fixed width and height. Once I set container `height:40` then `TextField` hint text and text are not aligned centerLeft but if I set Container `height:50` then all things go fine. I have also tried to set fontSize but still not working. I have checked these are the questions : [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68496407/flutter-textfield-hint-text-not-align-center) , [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731910/how-to-align-hint-text-into-centre-in-text-field), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537733/flutter-textfield-hint-text-not-aligned-center-horizontally) and also tried some other code also but won't worked while container `height:40`.

This is the Code that I am using :

```
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 40,
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
      hintText: 'Enter your text',
      border: InputBorder.none,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

UI(Out Put) when `height:50` (perfect):

[image] [image]

UI(Out Put) when `height:40`(Issue with alignment):

[image][image]

Comment: My guess is that the default height for `TextFormField` is more than 40, but less then 50, so if you set the `Container` height to 40, the alignment is working fine, but part of the area occupied by `TextFormField` does not fit into the `Container` but overflows at the bottom.

Comment: The default and material height is 48 afaik

Comment: @PeterKoltai I am also thinking same like you but I below answer's solution works perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isDense: true`, it will adapt the height.

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
  hintText: 'Enter your text',
  isDense: true,
```